# Django filter class on many to many field

Tags: django

Hello i am pretty new to django and i am facing an issue.

I have a user model that is linked to a group model through a many to many field.

I want a custom filter class that would be able to return every instances of my user model that has a group with a group name containing a specific string.

here is my group model containing the realation :

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    group_name = models.CharField(db_column='groupName', max_length=255)
    group_description = models.CharField(
    db_column='groupDescription', max_length=255, blank=True)
    created_by = models.EmailField(db_column='createdBy')
    created_date = models.DateField(db_column='creationDate', auto_now=True)
    group_users = models.ManyToManyField(
    User, blank=True, related_name='groups', through=UserGroup)
```

i am using a genericApiView and here is the filter class is use:

```
class UsersFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = {
        'user_email': ['iexact', 'istartswith', 'iendswith', 'icontains'],
    }
```

i wanted to add a group field that would be able to do the right query.

i read the doc and did not found a way to do it.

Has anyone ever done some thing comparable and give me a little help ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "custom filter class".

Comment: thanks for answering so fast, in my controller that is a GenericAPIView, i want to be able to call my api like /api/ref/users?groups=mygroup" wich will return the users having the group with 'mygroup' name. For the moment i defined a filter class called UserFilter wichh i want to modify to make my research on the group

Comment: Are you using Django REST Framework? You don't need a filter class, you just need to override `get_queryset` on your viewset to return the data filtered however you want.

Comment: i updated my question, in fact i already did override my get queryset to perform an other filter. I saw in the documentation that there was a filter.method that maybe could do the trick. Any clue to do this with the filter method ?